# OpenCV 3.4.4 make error with mingw32-make "persistence.cpp"

Tags: opencv, installation, codeblocks, mingw32, cmake-gui

I am currently installing OpenCV3.4.4 in ordre to use it with Code::Blocks. I used CMake GUI to Configure and Generates the binaries.

But when I'm using 'mingw32-make' to finish the installation, an error occurs about strnlen which apparently is not define. I have the following message :

"
C:\opencv\sources\modules\core\src\persistence.cpp: In function 'char* icvGets(CvFileStorage*, char*, int)':
C:\opencv\sources\modules\core\src\persistence.cpp:71:46: error: 'strnlen' was not declared in this scope
             size_t sz = strnlen(ptr, maxCount);
                                              ^
C:\opencv\sources\modules\core\src\persistence.cpp:82:46: error: 'strnlen' was not declared in this scope
             size_t sz = strnlen(ptr, maxCount);
                                              ^
modules\core\CMakeFiles\opencv_core.dir\build.make:901: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/persistence.cpp.obj' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/persistence.cpp.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:1671: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:161: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2"

"

I've read some other forum asking to change some variables in CMake GUI but for other issues and I did not succeed to find the same as me. I hope that someone could help me. thank you

Answer (score 0):

If this is useful for you, I was able to compile OpenCV 3.1.0 with MinGW32.

I have not been able to compile OpenCV3.4.7 with MinGW32 (I think that this backward compatibility has been abandoned), but I succeeded to compile OpenCV3.4.7 with MinGW64.